# set up mongo db across 2 servers

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am currently setting up a Mongo database in a production environment. It will be running off of 2 servers - I want to set it up so that one server can fail over to the other when and if necessary.

I am new to Mongo and have a SQL Server database. I admit that I am not sure how to set this up so would like some help with such. Any tutorials of similar on the web that could help me? Or any advice regarding such a setup?

Comment: If you are looking for replication, this has all the information : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replication in MongoDB will help you to achieve your goal.

Here is how replication works in MongoDB

1. A replica set is a set of 2 or more mongod cluster ( 3 is always preferred over 2 )
2. One among them will be a primary and rest are secondaries.
3. In case of failover of primary, secondaries will form an election and choose the new primary. ( automated failover )
4. There are different member configuration available for replica set, details [in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication/#member-configurations)
5. Deployment details are [in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/)

Comment: Thanks for this feedback - from research I now understand that I should have 3 but unfortunately that is not possible due to server restrictions. I am going to take another server and use this an arbiter - meaning that this can participate in elections - in turn having 3 servers participating. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, thats correct. arbiter in replica set is a light weight solution. It will not store any data in it. 


When you have a 3 member replica set, the configuration will be Primary,secondary and arbiter. Arbiter will be only participating in election and it will never vote for itself ( which is obvious :) ) 

Clients which are replica aware, will never talk to this arbiter.

Comment: Great - thanks for enhacning my understanding. So in the election process, it will always move to the secondary of primary fail?

Comment: Yes. As you have arbiter, in case of failure of primary, secondary will be elected as primary and client will start writing/reading to/from it

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB 2 member replication will help you.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/master-slave/#replica-set-equivalent

Comment: I just tried to use this method and it does not work. The server that is up remains as Primary, but clients cannot connect (PHP): No suitable servers found (`serverselectiontryonce` set): [connection error calling ismaster on 'app01.pridedallas.com:27017'] [Failed connecting to 'app02.pridedallas.com:27017': A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ]